# German characters not rendering in window.open link on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im having an odd problem with javascript window.open() as regards German characters. When I have a link like this:
http://maps.zh.ch/?topic=AVfarbigwwwZH&scale=1000&adr=R%C3%B6merweg%2051%20Embrach&markers=ring
The link fails to properly open the url because we have a German word in there. This: R%C3%B6merweg%2051% is supposed to read this: Römerweg 51. This only appears to happen in chrome. On Firefox, it displays fine and the link is opened fine. So we have a situation where the code works fine on Firefox, but not chrome. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Opens fine for me in Chrome, too.

Comment: it works with 50.0.2661.102 m

Comment: Figured out what the issue is. I needed to use encodeURI() on the url before passing it to open.window().